# Oxidative chlorination mechanism (sulfide to sulfonyl chloride)

Tags: reaction-mechanism, redox, synthesis, organosulfur-compounds

I cannot find much guidance in the literature. Any ideas as to what the mechanism of this reaction might be?

[image: http://malaria.ourexperiment.org/data/files/2141.png]

Comment: The mechanisms of oxidations of this type are often difficult to study since there are multiple pathways they can follow. For instance, I can draw valid-looking dipolar and radical mechanisms for this reaction. When I'm back in my office and have access to ChemDraw, I will post both as answers.

Comment: Regarding the species involved, $\ce{Cl_2}$ in water should disproportionate to $\ce{ClO^-}$, and possibly also create $\ce{CH_3COCl}$. If you think about this species as well, what reaction you can draw?

Answer (score 5):

As Ben Norris already pointed out, these processes are typical a bit complex. It is however conceivable that the direct oxidation of the thioether **1** is among the first steps involved.

[image: oxidation of thioether]

While the oxidative cleavage of PMB (= 4-methoxybenzyl) ethers, often applied as protecting groups, is assumed to take place in the methoxy-substituted arene, here the electron transfer mostly likely proceeds from the sulfur atom, leading to the sulfur-centred radical cation **2**.

In the presence of a nucleophile, this species is likely to break down en route to the radical **3**.

[image: cleavage of radical cation]

Whether a disulfide, formed upon dimerization of **3**, will take part in the further course of the reaction is beyond these musings.